# How to solve AssertionError when loading LLaMa 2 70B with Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, large-language-model

I am trying to run LLaMa 2 70B in Google Colab, using a GGML file: `TheBloke/Llama-2-70B-Chat-GGML`. Here is my current code that I am using to run it:

```
!pip install huggingface_hub
model_name_or_path = "TheBloke/Llama-2-70B-Chat-GGML"
model_basename = "llama-2-70b-chat.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin"

from huggingface_hub import hf_hub_download
from llama_cpp import Llama

model_path = hf_hub_download(repo_id=model_name_or_path, filename=model_basename)

# GPU
lcpp_llm = None
lcpp_llm = Llama(
    model_path=model_path,
    n_threads=2, # CPU cores
    n_batch=512, # Should be between 1 and n_ctx, consider the amount of VRAM in your GPU.
    n_gpu_layers=32 # Change this value based on your model and your GPU VRAM pool.
    )
```

However, when I tried to load LLaMa 2, I got an AssertionError like this:

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-da96b2fa6a04> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 # GPU
      2 lcpp_llm = None
----> 3 lcpp_llm = Llama(
      4     model_path=model_path,
      5     n_threads=2, # CPU cores

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/llama_cpp/llama.py in __init__(self, model_path, n_ctx, n_parts, n_gpu_layers, seed, f16_kv, logits_all, vocab_only, use_mmap, use_mlock, embedding, n_threads, n_batch, last_n_tokens_size, lora_base, lora_path, low_vram, tensor_split, rope_freq_base, rope_freq_scale, n_gqa, rms_norm_eps, verbose)
    311             self.model_path.encode("utf-8"), self.params
    312         )
--> 313         assert self.model is not None
    314 
    315         self.ctx = llama_cpp.llama_new_context_with_model(self.model, self.params)

AssertionError:
```

This error is strange for me, since earlier I have loaded a bin file for LLaMa 2 13B model, and the code worked without error. So, could you tell me about what I did wrong in the code, and how to fix this problem so I could run the model in Google Colab?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following parameter to the constructer fixed the error for me, GQA = Grouped Query Attention

n_gqa=8

See more information here: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/model_doc/llama2

Running the initial code from command line gives more detailed errors:

error loading model: llama.cpp: tensor 'layers.0.attention.wk.weight' has wrong shape; expected  8192 x  8192, got  8192 x  1024